# What effects does extending have on memory in Java?

Tags: java, memory-management, extends

So when you make an instance of a class such as:

```
class Example {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          Example example = new Example();

     }

}
```

Will anymore resources be used if I did:

```
class Item {

     public Item() {
          //empty
     }

}


class Example extends Item {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          Example example = new Example();

     }

}
```

If so, why?

Comment: You need X more memory to store the `.class` file for `Item`. You really shouldn't worry about that.

Comment: For each base class or interface `Example` uses, I would expect each instance of `Example` to be 4 bytes larger. Not significant at all unless you make zillions, like if you use an object to represent something tiny like a node on a graph.

Comment: So it won't take much memory? Lets say I had one method in `Item`. 100 different classes extending `Item` wouldn't take much more memory than 100 different classes putting that method in individually. (all methods would be overriden if extended)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an insignificant increase in memory usage due to the fact that you have an extra class to load.  If you have 100 subclasses of `Item`, you would have 100 extra classes to load ... and if you take it far enough the extra memory usage for the extra code *will* be significant.

However, an instance of `Example` will occupy the same space as an instance of `Item` because `Example` does not declare any instance fields.  Note that extra methods or method overloads do not contribute to the size of an instance.

Comment: So when you have an instance of `Example`, a space in memory the same size as `Example` will be used for `Item`? (if `Example` had no original methods)

Comment: That is correct.  And it won't make any difference if there are extra methods in `Example`.  Methods do not occupy any memory in an instance.  They only use memory at the class level ... and that is a once-off thing, so it is probably going to be insignificant.